# Откуда взялся "Питер"?

Tags: имена-собственные

Если город называется Санкт-Петербург, то, интересно было бы узнать, откуда взялось сокращение Питер — через И?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Город Санкт-Петербург в 18 веке обычно именовался - Санкт-Питербурх.

> М. В. Ломоносов. 1743 апреля 23. Доношение в Академию Наук об удержании денег, полученных в счет жалованья (1743) А как я, нижайший, **в Санкт-Питербурх прибыл**, то в зачет заслуженного своего адъюнктского жалованья из Академии Наук брал же...

Походный журнал Петра Первого :
[image: Санкт-Питербурх]

Выдержка из сетевого ресурса http://moscow.gramota.ru/map112.shtml :
 ""И еще немного об истории топонима
Санкт-Петербург. Следует помнить, что город-
крепость Санктпитербурх, основанный Петром
I в мае 1703 года в устье Невы, был назван не
в честь самого царя, а в честь его небесного
покровителя — апостола Петра. А вот какой
интересный материал об изменениях формы
названия города собрал в своей книжке «Имена
городов: вчера и сегодня (1917—1992)»
топонимист Е. М. Поспелов:
«Крепость после сооружения в ней собора
Петра и Павла стала называться
Петропавловской , а ее первоначальное
название (т. е. Санктпитербурх. — М. Г. )
оказалось распространенным на возникший
при ней город. Специального акта,
определяющего название, присвоенное городу,
принято не было. А лица из иноязычного
окружения Петра, говорившие
преимущественно на немецком, шведском,
голландском, английском языках, а также его
русские сподвижники, в той или иной мере
владевшие этими языками, название «город
Святого Петра» произносили и писали каждый
на свой лад. Поэтому в источниках первой
четверти XVIII в. Оно встречается более чем в
тридцати вариантах. Разнобой касался всех
компонентов названия: Санкт, Сант и Сан;
Питер и Петер (часто в родительном падеже:
Питерс, Петерс); бург, бурх и бурк , причем
все это в одно, два или даже три слова. Так,
среди вариантов, встречающихся в письмах
Петра Великого, находим: Санктъпетерсъбурк
(20.VII.1703), Санктпитербурх (20.IX.1703),
Питербурх (17.V.1706), Санктпетерзбурк
(20.XI.1710); позже преобладают варианты с
Питер : Санкт-Питер-Бург (28.IV.1714), Санктъ
Питербурх (13.I.1720). В газете «Ведомости»
название упоминается в формах
Санктпитербурх (XII.1703), Сантъпитербург
(I.1704), Санктпитерзбурк и
Санктъпетерзбурк (V,VI.1711), но чаще
Санктъпитербурх . Только начиная с июля
1724 г. «Ведомости» вместо -Питер- начинают
постоянно печатать -Петер- . Это позволяет
считать, что неофициальное название города
Питер , широко употребляющееся и в
настоящее время, получило распространение
до 1724 г. Установившаяся после смерти Петра
Великого чисто немецкая форма Санкт-
Петербург, наряду с сокращенной формой
Петербург, без колебаний употреблялась до
1914 г. Вскоре после начала Первой мировой
войны актом от 18(31) августа 1914 г. немецкое
название было заменено на русское
Петроград. Очевидно, что смысл названия при
этом переименовании был изменен: город стал
называться уже не в честь святого, а по имени
самого императора».

Comment: Грумант, а самому что-то написать слабо?
Только мои комменты удалять?

Я повторю. Ваш косяк том, что Питербурх само по себе уже производное от Питер. И никакие картинки не ответа на вопрос о появлении там И. А вот голландское произношение дает ответ на это вопрос.

Comment: В приведенном тексте по ссылке написано :  
>... **название «город Святого Петра» произносили и писали каждый на свой лад**. Поэтому в источниках первой четверти XVIII в. **оно встречается более чем в тридцати вариантах.**  

Вариант **Питербурх** прижился в обычной речи и использовался достаточно долго. Сокращенное имя города упомянуто впервые в литературе в "Недоросле" :  
>Д. И. Фонвизин. Недоросль (так называемый ранний «Недоросль») (1764) Сказывают, что у вас в Питере едят лягушек, черепах и какие-то еще устрицы.

Answer (score 1):

От голландского Herr Pieter (кажется так), коим "титулом" себя велел величать Петр.

Comment: А само сокращение тогда же появилось?

Comment: Это трудно сказать... 
Устная речь до какого-то момента почти не фиксировалась "на бумаге"
Но оно вполне естественно. Рано или поздно должно было появиться. 
Ведь именно так звучал Петербург "по-иностанному". На французский его не переводили, так что конец XVIII века - самое позднее. Имхо.

Comment: А  другие  русские  города  с  названием,  начинающемся  на  "санкт"  есть ?

Comment: Нет. Вы историю СПб посмотрите. Это единственный город, названный в честь святого. Русской культуре это несвойственно. Петр, основывая город, последовал западной традиции. Причем смешал католический обычай с голландским языком, хотя среди голландцев протестантов поболее будет. Видимо потому, что тогдашняя Голландия (Нидерланды) была поболее нынешней - и включала католический франкоязычный юг современной Бельгии. Вот так примерно и получился этот гибрид. С точностью до деталей, которые, конечно можно обсуждать.

Comment: >Это единственный город, названный в честь святого.

Мягко выражаясь, очень спорное утверждение. Петропавлоск-Камчатский и Елисаветград (ныне Кировоград)явно, и вероятно почти все отымённые города имперского периода, включая Екатеринбург, названы в честь святых. Правда приставку "Санкт-" больше нигде не добавляли.

Comment: >Петропавлоск-Камчатский  
  
Апостолы... Да и то спорно.
>Основан в 1740 году Второй Камчатской экспедицией, назван по имени кораблей экспедиции «Святой Пётр» и «Святой Павел».  
  
(Вики)

>Елисаветград  
  
Это какая же святая? Даже не вспомню.

>Екатеринбург  
  
Да ежику же ясно, что город царицы, а не святой Екатерины. 

У нас села назывались по храму, в них стоящему, потом могло перенестись на город. Но так вот, с бухты-барахты... СПб считаю единственным.

Comment: >Апостолы... Да и то спорно.

**Святые**  апостолы Пётр и Павел.

>Это какая же святая? Даже не вспомню.

[Для памяти](http://days.pravoslavie.ru/Life/life6575.htm). Город основан на месте Крепости Святой Елисаветы, так что тут тоже без вопросов.